# Can I convert a reference to a React Component into JSON code?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-state

I want to JSONify the state of a React component and dump the state into a database. My code currently looks like this:

```
const [exampleState, setExampleState] = useState([
   {
      componentName: "Test component",
      component: <TestComponent props={testComponentData} />,
   }.
   {
      componentName: "Another test component",
      component: <AnotherTestComponent props={anotherTestComponentData} />
   }
]);
```

Would it be possible to JSONify the state as is, store it in a database, retrieve the data from the database at a later date as a JSON, then convert it back into a valid state?

If not, what is the recommended procedure to convert this state into a JSON object that I could store in a database and convert it back from a JSON object into state again?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632862/can-i-convert-a-reference-to-a-react-component-into-json/71633243#71633243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably try createElement. Haven't use it for a long time but the following should work.

```
const Renderer = () => {
    const item = {
       component: 'TestComponent',
       props: { testComponentData: 'someData' }
    }
    
    const TestComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`./${item.component}`));
    return React.createElement(TestComponent, item.props) //TestComponent should be a component and not a string.
}
```