# Can I convert a reference to a React Component into JSON?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

I want to JSONify the state of a React component and dump the state into a database. My code currently looks like this:

```
const [exampleState, setExampleState] = useState([
   {
      componentName: "Test component",
      component: <TestComponent props={testComponentData} />,
   }.
   {
      componentName: "Another test component",
      component: <AnotherTestComponent props={anotherTestComponentData} />
   }
]);
```

Would it be possible to JSONify the state as is, store it in a database, retrieve the data from the database at a later date as a JSON, then convert it back into a valid state?

If not, what is the recommended procedure to convert this state into a JSON object that I could store in a database and convert it back from a JSON object into state again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the whole component can be store to DB like this way. The more reasonable way should be store the `component name` and `props` to DB and make   the `react component` to stay in the frontend.

A brief example maybe like this.

DB

```
[
    {
      name: 'TestComponent',
      props: testComponentData
    },
    {
      name: 'AnotherTestComponent',
      props: anotherTestComponentData
    }
]
```

Frontend

```
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';
import AnotherTestComponent from './AnotherTestComponent';

const renderComponent = (name, props) => {
  const mapNameToComponent = {
    TestComponent: TestComponent,
    AnotherTestComponent: AnotherTestComponent
  }

  const Component = mapNameToComponent[name];
  
  if (!Component) return null;
  return <Component {...props} />
}

const Page = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [props, setProps] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // call api to getDB data
    // The data structure of dbData just like the DB shows
    const dbData = getDB();

    // store the DB data in the state
    const TestComponentData = dbData[0];
    setName(TestComponentData.name);
    setProps(TestComponentData.props);
  }, [])
  
  // choice which component you want to render by name and props
  return renderComponent(name, props)
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this myself. If you try to JSONify what I have above, it will return this error: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".


So keeping state as simple as possible with simply strings and using a dictionary/hash map to retrieve the component like in the example you provided is probably one of the most efficient ways